# How to reduce image loading time

Tags: image, tapestry

I am developing web application for smart phones using tapestry. I have a loop in my index page. I am putting more than five images in that loop. Each image size is 5KB. But its take more than 150ms for loading(each image).

Is there is any way to reduce image loading time. Please any one help me.

code:

Index.tml

```
<t:loop source="topRatedVideoDatas" value="videoItemProperty" index="currIndex" encoder="encoder">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="list">
<td>
<img src="${videoItemProperty.image}"  width="130" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</t:loop>
```

Index.java

```
public List<ItemProperty> getTopRatedVideoDatas() {
        List<ItemProperty> videoItemProperties = null;
        try {
            final GetData getData = new HttpGetData();
            final String json = getData.getContent("http://localhost:8080/sample/getTopRatedItems" );
            final JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            if(object.optString(Constants.CODE).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STATUS_CODE_1)) {
                videoItemProperties = new ArrayList<ItemProperty>();
                final String[] result = object.optString(Constants.ITEMS).split(Constants.COMMA);
                for(int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < result.length; innerIndex++) {
                    videoItemProperties.add(itemProperties.get(innerIndex).getPropety().get(innerIndex));
                }
            }
        } catch(final Exception e) {

        }
        return videoItemProperties;
    }
```

Comment: could you provide your code snippet where you render this images?

Comment: Hi sody I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: As I see you have additional http request inside your server code. But it can affect only page content loading time not image response time. Do you use just url to static resource in videoItemProperty.getImage() or you generate images by some servlet code?

Comment: Performance questions should always be prefaced by performance metrics. Have you measured where the time is being spent?  For example, is the problem the initial page render time on the server, or the time to load each image?

I suspect your performance issue is not related to Tapestry, but is related to the fact that you do a HTTP call in the middle of rendering your page.

Comment: @sody ya I am using url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my above comment; I would suggest

- move the logic that assembles the video data out of your page code and into a service
- come up with a reasonable way to cache the video data result, and/or periodically update it in the background

This will result in the page rendering faster; the next step is to see how long it takes to download the images themselves.

You can look into rescaling and compressing the images. You can ensure that the images have a unique URL for their content, and a far future expires header (and/or ETag) to ensure that the browser downloads them once and only once, and keeps them in local cache.

You can do more advanced tricks if that is not enough. You could initially download a fast low resolution thumbnail, and then replace it (in place) with a higher resolution thumbnail after initial page load (though you get some of this benefit when using the progressive JPEG format.

But again, start with measurements and goals, and figure out where the problems actually lie. FF and Chrome both have excellent tools for getting that information. Use that.

Comment: And, of course, a CDN will help. Also, loading five images may hit you against browser request limits, so splitting the image loads across multiple hostnames may also help.